# Product count for anchored category in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want a script or idea by which I can get product count for an anchored category.

I tried `loadProductCount()` method from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection` class but it's not returning product count instead it returns an array. Please take a look on the array given below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [entity_type_id] => 3
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [parent_id] => 0
            [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2011-10-31 16:14:51
            [path] => 1
            [position] => 0
            [level] => 0
            [children_count] => 163
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 2
            [entity_type_id] => 3
            [attribute_set_id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2011-10-31 16:14:51
            [updated_at] => 2012-09-07 20:51:21
            [path] => 1/2
            [position] => 1
            [level] => 1
            [children_count] => 163
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 117
        [entity_type_id] => 3
        [attribute_set_id] => 0
        [parent_id] => 2
        [created_at] => 2012-09-07 16:51:28
        [updated_at] => 2012-09-10 07:55:24
        [path] => 1/2/117
        [position] => 13
        [level] => 2
        [children_count] => 15
    )
```

....

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the products for an anchor category use this

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getProductCollection()->count()
```

If you for example want to show the product count on product listing page in `/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` use this:

```
<?php if( $_category->getIsAnchor() ): ?>
    <span class="product-count" ><span class="count"><?php echo $_category->getProductCollection()->count(); ?></span> Artikel</span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="product-count" ><span class="count"><?php echo $_category->getProductCount(); ?></span> Artikel</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getProductCount` function on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` should return the information you are after.

Comment: **getProductCount** from **Mage_Catalog_Model_Category** will count product from single category but I want products from child categories to be included in product count.

Comment: @user739696 Man. probably you want to dig into the Code of Category Management of backend. You can Notice there magento shows the total number of products in a category which includes the child products also.